# Plotting data using highcharts piechart in flask web application

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, flask, highcharts

I am trying to plot pandas dataframe from a python function and display it on a web server using Highcharts pie chart. I can get the data from the function to the web server as json data through flask. but when I want to display it the chart is empty. Through the web console I also made sure that the data format going into the Highcharts is correct but still nothing.

Here I am retrieving the panda dataframe and sending it to the web server through flask:

```
actype_json = actype.to_json(orient = 'records')

@app.route('/data/airport', methods = ['GET'])
def broadcast_data():
    return eval(json.dumps(actype_json))

@app.route('/')
def plotgraph():
    return render_template('airport.html')
```

On my HTML file, I tried to use AJAX to call for the data and plot it in a Highcharts Pie Chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <script>

        function GetUpdatedData(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "/data/airport",
            })
              .done(function( data ) {
                  console.log( data );
                  DrawGraph(data);
                }); 
        }   

        function DrawGraph(dataset) {

            // Radialize the colors
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                    colors: Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
                            return {
                                    radialGradient: {
                                            cx: 0.5,
                                            cy: 0.3,
                                            r: 0.7
                                    },
                                    stops: [
                                            [0, color],
                                            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                                    ]
                            };
                    })
            });

            // Build the chart
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                            plotBackgroundColor: null,
                            plotBorderWidth: null,
                            plotShadow: false,
                            type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                            text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                            enabled: true,
                                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                                            style: {
                                                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                                            },
                                            connectorColor: 'silver'
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Aircraft',
                        data: [dataset]
                }]
            });
            setTimeout(GetUpdatedData, 1500);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the screenshot of the Highcharts Pie Chart that I am seeing:

[image]

The response tab is showing the format of the data trying to be plotted on  Highchart. Any advice will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Why do call DrawGraph with data.data as argument? Does the JSON have any field named 'data'? Do you get any error in the console? Make sure dataset.data points to list of dictionaries - use Chrome debugger.

Comment: My mistake, DrawGraph is only calling data as argument. But still the graph is empty. There's no error at all. For the JSON there is no field name data. I believe my format is already the format Highcharts need but I don't know why it is not plotting it.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a simple mistake when adding data to `series.data` array. Note that your data is actually a correct Highcharts data array with point objects inside:

**data:**

```
[{
  "AC TYPE": "B773",
  "y": 35
}, {
  "AC TYPE": "B77W",
  "y": 16
}]
```

However, you've added this array inside another one like that:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Aircraft',
  data: [dataset]
}]
```

This gives you an invalid data format with two nested arrays:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Aircraft',
    data: [[{
      "AC TYPE": "B773",
      "y": 35
    }, {
      "AC TYPE": "B77W",
      "y": 16
    }]]
  }]
```

Remove the wrapping array and the chart should be rendered correctly.

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/49rhpmyg/